# Oracle SQL Developer lowercase identifiers for migrated DBs?

Tags: oracle, codeigniter, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-migration, uppercase

I'm currently porting a Code Igniter based application from MySQL to Oracle (11g) for a specific client. Both the MySQL and Oracle back-ends have to work in conjunction (i.e. we cannot drop the one or the other). 
The MySQL DB uses around 100 tables of which ALL identifiers are in lowercase. When I migrate this DB to Oracle, using Oracle's SQL Developer tool, I end up with a 'properly' converted DB, but... with all uppercase identifiers.

Now, for normal usage this isn't really a problem, but the issue arises when using the CI Active Record class. It generates queries to the effect of:
SELECT "somecolumn" FROM "sometable" WHERE "someothercolumn" = somevalue

The issue is that when the " quotes are used for these identifiers, Oracle forces these identifiers to be interpreted in a case sensitive way, which in this case is wreaking havoc.

Patching the core code of CI and/or the application to either make all queries use case insensitive identifiers (i.e. by dropping the usage of the " quotes around the identifiers) or to convert all identifiers to uppercase ones on the fly, is IMO not desired, as a potential future framework upgrade is then compromised. Renaming ALL MySQL identifiers to become in uppercase is also a very unattractive scenario and has an even bigger impact on the application itself -- not an option for sure.

Instead, what I would like to achieve, is to have the migration process (i.e. using SQL Developer) simply respecting the case of the source DB and to perform the conversion exactly as it does up to now, with the exception that the identifiers do not get changed to their uppercase version.

I have searched a fair deal online to find a way to achieve this, and so far it has been to no avail.

Does anyone know if this can be done, and if so: how?
Is the conversion to all uppercase identifiers by any chance a global DB setting, perhaps? 
I would have assumed this to be a trivial thing, but I haven't been able to figure it out so far and what little related references that I did come across do not sound very promising...

Answer (score 0):

If you can acquire a schema script created by the database migration all you need to do is change the identifiers ( tablenames, view names, column names etc ) to be surrounded with double quotation marks. (I'm not sure if SQL Developer migrations actually has the option to preserve the case).

Without the quote marks Oracle will assume all identifiers are case-insensitive.  However this is stored internally as upper case strings in the data dictionary. By using quote marks will force Oracle to use the exact case for the schema objects.

eg.

```
create table Customers
( 
  Name varchar2(100), 
  CreationDate date not null 
);
```

will create CUSTOMERS internally in the data-dictionar and you can write queries like:

```
select name, creationdate from customers;
```

alternatively:

```
create table "Customers"
( 
  "Name" varchar2(100), 
  "CreationDate" date not null 
);
```

will create "Customers" internally. You can only write queries using quotes and exact case:

```
select "Name", "CreationDate" from "Customers";
```

Comment: A thing I forgot to mention: I came across a post on the Oracle forums that was pretty much to the effect of what you suggest. It's in this thread: https://forums.oracle.com/message/10199667
It sounded promising at first, but around post #6 it becomes clear that it is a troublesome road, and not one that lends itself to be easily repeated.
In light of such extensive 'patching of something' it would probably be better to patch the CI code. :O
I still hope SQL Developer itself (I use v4.0) can somehow be told to respect the case of the identifiers....

Comment: Yeah, a quick google reveals it's a common complaint when working with codeigniter/oracle. It seems there aren't many other options without going into the codeigniter source.

Answer (score 0):

I have hit this before and simply edited oci8_driver.php (../system/database/oci) as follows:

```
// The character used for excaping
var $_escape_char = '"';
```

to

```
// The character used for excaping
var $_escape_char = '';
```

Stewart